# How to get the range (i.e., the line number) of all functions in a file in C?

Tags: c, function, ctags, line-numbers

I want to get both the beginning and ending line numbers of all functions in a file in C. Does any one know that whether there is a easy-to-use tool in Linux for this purpose?

Comment: Try [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618018/11067496) demonstrates how to get both the start and end line numbers with `ctags`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ ctags -x --c-kinds=f filename.c
```

This only gives the starting line of each function, but perhaps that is good enough.

If the code was written using fairly common conventions, the function should end with a single line containing `}` in the first column, so it is fairly easy to get the last line given the first:

```
awk 'NR > first && /^}$/ { print NR; exit }' first=$FIRST_LINE filename.c
```

Comment: Why this message occurs? 
ctags: unrecognized option '--c-kinds=f'
        Try `ctags --help' for a complete list of options.

Comment: @user1038013 You probably have a version of ctags that does not recognize --c-kinds.  The purpose of that option is to emit information only for functions (not #DEFINES, etc).  You could omit that option and grep for "function".

Comment: --c-kinds is available in Exuberant ctags 5.5.4

Comment: OK. I'v tried the latest version and it worked. Thank you. However, I still have to find the ending line numbers.

Comment: Did you find a way? Im struggling !

Comment: Edited to add a proposed, non-robust solution to get the last line.