# ctags: To get C function end line number

Tags: parsing, awk, tags, ctags, exuberant-ctags

is it possible via ctags to get the function end line number as well

```
"ctags -x --c-kinds=f filename.c"
```

Above command  lists the function definition start line-numbers. Wanted a way to get the function end line numbers.

Other Approaches:

```
awk 'NR > first && /^}$/ { print NR; exit }' first=$FIRST_LINE filename.c
```

This needs the code to be properly formatted

Example:
filename.c

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdlib.h>
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5    const char  *name;
  6 
  7     int a=0
  8     printf("name");
  9     printf("sssss: %s",name);
 10 
 11     return 0;
 12 }
 13 
 14 void code()
 15  {
 16         printf("Code \n");
 17  }
 18 
 19 int code2()
 20    {
 21         printf("code2 \n");
 22         return 1
 23    }
 24
```

Input: filename and the function start line no.

```
Example:

    Input: filename.c  3
    Output: 12

    Input : filename.c 19
    Output : 23
```

Is there any better/simple way of doing this ?

Comment: a sample input file will help to get more answers.

Comment: @karakfa Added the sample example. Appreciate any help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

doesn't handle curly braces within comments but should handle blocks within functions, please give it a try...

```
$ awk -v s=3 'NR>=s && /{/              {c++} 
              NR>=s && /}/ && c && !--c {print NR; exit}' file
```

finds the matching brace for the first one after the specified start line number s.

Comment: Cool. This works.
Changes : Add a closing ' at the end. and change NR=>s to NR>=s

Answer (score 9):

C/C++ parser of Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) has end: field.

```
jet@localhost tmp]$ cat -n foo.c
     1  int
     2  main( void )
     3  {
     4  
     5  }
     6  
     7  int
     8  bar (void)
     9  {
    10  
    11  }
    12  
    13  struct x {
    14      int y;
    15  };
    16  
[jet@localhost tmp]$ ~/var/ctags/ctags --fields=+ne -o - --sort=no foo.c
main    foo.c   /^main( void )$/;"  f   line:2  typeref:typename:int    end:5
bar foo.c   /^bar (void)$/;"    f   line:8  typeref:typename:int    end:11
x   foo.c   /^struct x {$/;"    s   line:13 file:   end:15
y   foo.c   /^  int y;$/;"  m   line:14 struct:x    typeref:typename:int    file:
```

Comment: This works. Can we get the start and end line in the same command.