# How can I get a statistic about function length?

Tags: c

I have to work on a rather large legacy code base.
The code is literally from another time and things were done differently then.
Since function calls were rather expensive and slow in the past, the functions tend to be rather long.

Is there a way to automatically get a list of function names and their length in LOC?

I searched for some time but found no real solution. I remember there were static code analysis tools that would complain if a function was too long, but I did not find anything useful.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ctags](https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/man/ctags.1.html#language-specific-fields-and-extras) to analyze the code. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618018/ you can get all functions with start and end lines using

```
ctags --c-kinds=f --fields=+ne -o - yourfile.c
```

Testing this on some sample code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285893/dos-based-boggle-simulator gives the following result:

```
dictionary  boggle.c    /^void dictionary() {$/;"   f   line:168    typeref:typename:void   end:213
intidx  boggle.c    /^int intidx(int *arr, int arrLen, int idx) {$/;"   f   line:36 typeref:typename:int    end:44
main    boggle.c    /^int main(int argc, char** argv) {$/;" f   line:215    typeref:typename:int    end:246
newboard    boggle.c    /^void newboard() {$/;" f   line:73 typeref:typename:void   end:164
printhelp   boggle.c    /^void printhelp() {$/;"    f   line:62 typeref:typename:void   end:70
randLte boggle.c    /^int randLte(int upperBound) {$/;" f   line:48 typeref:typename:int    end:59
```

You can pipe this through for example Perl with a regular expression to extract the function name, start line, end line, and calculate the difference between end and start:

```
ctags --c-kinds=f --fields=+ne -o - boggle.c|perl -lne'm/\/\^([^)]+\)).*line:(\d+).*end:(\d+)/; print "$1 ".($3-$2)'
```

Result:

```
void dictionary() 45
int intidx(int *arr, int arrLen, int idx) 8
int main(int argc, char** argv) 31
void newboard() 91
void printhelp() 8
int randLte(int upperBound) 11
```

Comment: Well, my ctags does not know about --fields. Which package is yours from?

Comment: From Debian, `universal-ctags`. There is also a package `exuberant-ctags` but that is unmaintained. The `universal-ctags` package (for `apt`) provides version 5.9.20210829.0-1 which supports `--fields`. There is also a snap package that is more recent, I don't know for sure but I assume that version also supports this.

Comment: Excellent! Even the perl script works! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Here the awk version:
ctags --c-kinds=f --fields=+ne -o - my_file.c | awk '{split($(NF-3), b, ":"); split($NF, e, ":"); print $1, b[2], e[2], e[2]-b[2]}

Comment: It seems my awk solution works only sometimes... :-( And your perl script gives many duplicate lines, not sure what is correct now, but it is a start!  Thanks again!

Comment: @U.W. duplicate lines are strange, are they also present in the ctags output or does perl duplicate them somehow? As a quick and dirty solution you could of course pipe the final output to sort and uniq to remove the duplicates (`ctags ...|perl ...|sort|uniq`).

Comment: OK, *This* one seems to work:
`ctags --c-kinds=f --fields=+ne -o - my_file.c | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++){if (index($i,"line:")>0){split($i,b,":")}; if(index($i,"end:")>0){split($i,e,":")}}; print($1, b[2], e[2], e[2]-b[2])}'`

Comment: If you use u-ctags, readtags may help you. readtags takes a lisp-flavor format expression (-F option): `ctags --kinds-c=f --fields=+neSt -o - misc-utils/lsfd.c | readtags -t - -S '(<> (- $end $line) (- &end &line))' -F '(list (if (eq? $typeref-kind "typename") "" (list $typeref-kind " ")) $typeref-name " " $name $signature " " (- $end $line) #t)' -l`